# GoogleMaps Cluster Points using MarkerCluster Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have been trying to get Markers to Cluster on a Google map for a few days now and I'm lost on how to implement the code

I have this map ->
https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=211137438455901265530.0004cbb2cd7859b1b6c75&msa=0&ll=7.710992,-2.8125&spn=137.343849,307.96875

embedded on this website -> projectevomap.yolasite.com/

and want to add clusters like on this map ->
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html

this is the source code for that page ->

view-source:http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html

Basically, I could do with some guidance as to how I take the existing code and change it so that it displays my map, with clusters, on my site. I would have thought that it is simply by changing a small section in the source code to an address which directs it to my map rather than the example one (?) but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you're doing at the moment is embedding a Google Map into your web page.  Instead what you need to do is use the Google Maps API to add the Google Map directly to your page instead, i.e. not using your customised map.  You then have to add all the markers you need, to include the markerclusterer JS file, and to initialise the markerClusterer.

Like so in fact!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the script on here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#LoadingMap

I have entered my API key and set sensor to false.
when I try to then open the page on my site I get an error message, see for yourself (can't copy and paste the text) http://projectevomap.yolasite.com/testing.php

Comment: you must be using the wrong API key.  This is actually not a mandatory requirement, you can just remove it. Just try http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Comment: thanks. 

I now have a map, and the cluster feature installed to it, with a check-box to turn it off & default is with the feature switched on. 

So I guess the only bit I'm still missing is how to get the pins from my map (as seen on the websites homepage, and maintained through Google maps) on to the new map.

What would the steps to do this be? (ie how do I a- get the info from the old map? b- get the new map to display it?) sorry to not have figured this out but I'm new to script writing (other than stats analysis in R)


Thanks a lot for the help so far, I have been so lost!

Comment: the code segment is lines 346 to 413 in the view source window

Comment: So what you need is an array of markers.  You could either do this entirely in JS, or you could use something server-side (e.g. PHP) to extract the data from a database and then convert that to client-side javascript.  Your array should have latitude and longitude for each marker (or an address that can be looked up to get the coordinates), plus the content you want to add to the infowindows. Going back to the example, look at their data: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/data.json

Comment: Done!
But now I have markers I can see that markerclusterer is clearly not working... can you spot the mistake?

Comment: You need to create an array called markers, and append each marker into it (within your for loop), before calling `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`

Comment: I've spent the entire day trying this in a realtime editor to see what certain things in my script each do (which has taught me a lot about this language) -would the command be something like this?  markers.append(marker)
and where in the loop do I put it?
and can you suggest any beginners guide books on this - I'd like to learn so I can stop hassling you!

Comment: use `markers.push(marker);`  Do it towards the end of your loop, after you've created the marker variable.  See the example in my answer, above.

Comment: Excellent, the bit I was missing was:         var markers = [];

Here's the final code...
        var markers = [];

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
markers.push(marker)    
}

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular, there is a very easy-to-use directive made just for this:

https://github.com/arnauddri/ng-clustered-map/